# AS3 SWF File : Special Characters

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I downloaded a flash template and I need to add special characters (Greek Language) to:

> fonts.fla

After editing the file the flash is not loading anymore. Can someone help me with this issue?

Maybe this can help.

> NOTICE : THIS IS AN AS3 project and you can only add AS3 SWF files
>   When publishing your custom SWF file be sure to add this method to
>   your actionscript file: public function startModule():void { //inside
>   this method you can start your transitions to show the content }

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the downloaded fla uses a font that you don't have on your system.

Try changing the font for the textfield to _sans (which makes the textfield use the systems default _sans typeface).

Once that has been tested, if you need to change the font to something specific you should select the font from the dropdown menu and click the Embed button where you can specify which character sets you would like to embed.